# Can multiple visitors share the same IP address?

Tags: php, ip-address

Is it ever possible that there will be duplicate IP addresses for two devices at the same time accessing my website? this is how I get the IP address

```
$_SERVER['REMOTE_ADDR']
```

Comment: I feel like your real question is: "how do I uniquely identify users on my website?" Is that actually your question?

Comment: Nope, that i have sorted out :-)

Comment: Not just possible, but quite likely.

Comment: Just a reminder to stop you from pursuing this further in the wrong direction: TCP/IP is a *data delivery mechanism*. It makes sure data gets from A to B. Nothing more, nothing less. Identification is absolutely not in any way part of the protocol and it cannot really be used for in on a world-wide scale.

Comment: @Lappies Not if you're using IP address, you don't. It's incredibly common for people to share IPs. Entire office buildings and university campuses share a single public-facing IP.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Yes. If they are behind a firewall performing NAT, all of the connections could be coming from multiple clients, but will appear to be originating from the same IP Address.

Comment: Yep.  Happens all the time.  In my apartment, we all share the same connection, so we all have the same IP.

Comment: Doesn't have to be a "firewall", a simple router will do the same.

Comment: I need to identify a computer/device, and not the account by which they login on my website with, any idea guys :-( ?

Comment: I'd post a new question, but it almost certainly has been asked before. You essentially need a solution that involves cookies, and some server-tracked session id. Ideally, the session id is encrypted so that when decrypt it, you know if it's been tampered with (the cookie is, after all, stored on their end.) PHP almost certainly has all of this built in.

Comment: Set a cookie. Check for the cookie value later. Be aware of the fact that some users might be blocking cookies. However, don't think you can *really* solve the problem. 2 weeks ago, i did a firmware upgrade on my android device, which wiped everything from it. The only way for you to detect the device before the upgrade and the device after the upgrade are the same would be if you had my mac address, but there's no way from your php script to get that.

Comment: @Lappies the closest you can get to their computer (short of running a Java applet or some other code with local privilege escalation) is the device that's doing NAT for them. You can't uniquely identify an individual computer based on a web request. That would have scary implications for security if you could.

Comment: I think i should try out the applet

Comment: @Lappies: I wouldn't suggest that.

Comment: I really need something unique, the thing is, I will be running competitions on my site, were people can vote for something, the problem now comes in when a person has multiple accounts(email addresses), and can vote more then once, this is unfair to others :-(

Comment: There is no 100% reliable method of identifying users uniquely on the net. even if you could, consider someone who's got a home pc, a work pc, a cellphone, and a tablet. that's potentially 4 different ip addresses they can vote from. an IP address never has been and can never be a unique identifier for a "person".

Comment: Ah, ok, this is your actual problem.. how to implement a secure web voting mechanism. It's worth mentioning that this is an incredibly difficult problem to solve. I suspect that you're going to need to go the route of having users create an account, with some specific type of identifier that you can verify (SSN, drivers license #, alien id #). Unfortunately, nobody will want to give these out...

Comment: The ONLY way that I've ever seen this accomplished is to control the access ID to allow a vote. Ever been to a website that allows a survey to be done? Generally the ID that gets you to the survey is manufactured ahead of time and printed on a receipt. Once the ID is used to complete a survey, it's marked inactive and cannot be used again.